# Store a sequence of specific class types in Scala?

Tags: scala, akka

Trying to find a valid and flexible way to store a sequence of class types in Scala that I can later use to spin up new instances of that type:

```
class Event(

  val name: String,
  val channels: Seq[String],
  val processors: Seq[T] // a sequence of processor classes

)
```

Each processor in the sequence above is an Akka Actor class. I plan on creating a new Actor every time data is received by mapping out the processors like so:

```
event.processors.foreach { processorType =>
  val processor = newProcessor(processorType) // does all the Akka creation stuff
  processor ! Data
}
```

*Update:* apparently the above is rather correct, so how do we enforce that `Seq[T]` is processor-types only? So sticking in classes like `class Calculator extends Processor`

My guess is that there are some gotchas with Scala that I missed, so thanks for your help.

Comment: What's the error ? Should you use some kind of Seq[Actor] instead of Seq[T] ?

Comment: Scala IDE isn't auto-compiling today for some reason so actually didn't try to stick it in sbt. Is that actually supposed to compile? If yes, this is easier than I imagined.

Comment: P.s. I'll put an update, but there should probably be a way to enforce that type (restrict to processor types only)

Comment: val processors: Seq[T <: Processor] ?

Comment: Apparently this is a lot simpler than I imaged. Go Scala. Noah, I will test that and let you know if it's a valid answer.

Comment: Seq[T] is only valid if you have a type `T` defined or `T` is a type parameter. Doesn't seem to be the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Seq[T]` would only be valid if there is either a type `T` or a type parameter.

```
scala> class Event(val seq:Seq[T])
<console>:7: error: not found: type T
       class Event(val seq:Seq[T])
                               ^
```

To have a list of classes it has to be of a Seq[Class[_]].

Let's suppose the processors you mention are of type `Processor`. A smaller illustrative example:

```
scala>  trait Processor; class P1 extends Processor; class P2 extends Processor

scala> case class Event(val seq:Seq[Class[_ <: Processor]])
defined class Event

scala> Event(List(classOf[P1],classOf[P2]))
res4: Event = Event(List(class P1, class P2))

scala> res4.seq map { _.newInstance }
res6: Seq[Processor] = List(P1@43655bee, P2@337688d3)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is what `Props` is made for.  The advantage of using `Props` is that you could pass whatever parameters you want to your `Processor` constructors at runtime, instead of being restricted to using no-arg constructors.

One thing to note about `Props` is that it take a by-name `creator` argument, so when you see `Props(new TestActor)` the `TestActor` is not actually created at that moment.  It is created when you pass the `Props` to `actorOf()`.

To restrict the `Actor`s to be a subtype of `Processor` you could create a subtype of `Props`.

For example:

```
trait Processor extends Actor

class MyProps(creat: () ⇒ Processor) extends Props(creat)

object MyProps {
  def apply(creator: ⇒ Processor): MyProps = new MyProps(() => creator)
}
```

Your `Event` class would have a `Seq[MyProps]`.  Here's a sample test:

```
case class Event(      
  name: String,
  channels: Seq[String],
  processors: Seq[MyProps]       
)

class TestActor(bar: String) extends Processor {
  def receive = {
    case msg @ _ => println(bar + " " + msg)
  }
}

object SeqProps extends App {
  override def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val system = ActorSystem()

    val event = new Event("test", Seq("chan1", "chan2", "chan3"), 
      Seq(MyProps(new TestActor("baz")),
          MyProps(new TestActor("barz"))))

    event.processors.foreach { proc =>
      system.actorOf(proc) ! "go!"
    }

    system.shutdown()
  }
}
```

If you tried to pass a non-`Processor` to `MyProps()` it would fail at compile time.

```
scala> class NotProcessor extends Actor {
     |   def receive = emptyBehavior
     | }
defined class NotProcessor

scala> MyProps(new NotProcessor)
<console>:15: error: type mismatch;
 found   : NotProcessor
 required: Processor
              MyProps(new NotProcessor)
                      ^
```

Comment: `Props`? Where in Scala standard library is it? Any ways, this answer doesn't answer the question at all.

Comment: He's talking about akka.actor.Props, which indeed is needed to create Akka actors and thus I think this solution is also correct. Whether this or the other way is better depends on the unshown code in newProcessor(…).

Comment: `def system.actorOf(props: Props): ActorRef` creates an actor.