# How do I instantiate a new Scala class using a Class[T] parameter?

Tags: scala, akka

Here's the bit of code I have now, I am referencing any subclass of an Akka Actor called Processor:

```
def newProcessorProps(processorClass: Class[_ <: Processor]): Props = {
  Props(new processorClass).withDispatcher("dispatcher")
}
```

I just can't figure out how to instantiate a new class using that parameter. I don't think reflection isn't required here since I already have the class. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the class object as a value you can instantiate by calling the `newInstance()` method on it. So you'd do:

```
def newProcessorProps(processorClass: Class[_ <: Processor]): Props = {
  Props(processorClass.newInstance()).withDispatcher("dispatcher")
}
```

You can also use the Manifest of a type to instantiate an object of that type

```
def newProcessorProps[T <: Processor](implicit m: Manifest[T]): Props = {
  Props(m.erasure.newInstance().asInstanceOf[T]).withDispatcher("dispatcher")
}
```

And then call it for a specific processor like this:

```
newProcessorProps[SpecificProcessor]
```

This only works as long as T has a parameterless constructor I think.

Comment: Weird, this had an unintended consequence. I really like this approach, but the consequence is how to pass a value? The class references are stored in an Event class you can see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13093108/store-a-sequence-of-specific-class-types-in-scala

Comment: On second thought. You definitely don't need a manifest in this case. Just do `processorClass.newInstance()` instead of `new processorClass` in your code snippet.

Comment: That's comically simple ;) I think it's worthy of being added to the answer. I am, however, going to use a manifest elsewhere now that I better understand it!

Comment: Yeah. I understood Manifests fairly recently as well. They are pretty cool. So, I keep looking for places to cram it in and it's usually not needed :) I'll edit the answer to include the simple solution.

Answer (score 0):

Technically it's Props(processorClass) or Props[ProcessorClassType] as per the [documentation](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.1.0-RC1/#akka.actor.Props%24)